# react webapp manage which user can view which features

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty new to web dev. The web app I'm developing uses React and plain JS (I' not using flux or redux yet). I need to add a functionality to manage what user type can view which screen/ functionality. Can anyone point me to / give suggestions on where to start and possibly best practices on doing it?

Thanks

Comment: are you using any router?

Comment: I'm using EventEmitter to navigate screens, which is kind of a Router, but not really.